# font-variant:small-caps; vs text-transform:capitalize;

Tags: css

in css what is the difference between `font-variant:small-caps;` and `text-transform:capitalize;`

Comment: If you install Firebug in Firefox you can manipulate the CSS for any website and play with the various properties to see how they all work.

Comment: Simples: http://jsfiddle.net/MSPUq

Answer (score 69, accepted):

if you use `text-transform: capitalize` the word "stack overflow" will become "Stack Overflow", only the 1st letter of each word gets CAPS.

but if you use `font-variant: small-caps` the word "stack overflow" becomes "STACK OVERFLOW" but the height of the type-face will match the height of the lowercase letters before the CSS style was applied. so all CAPS but smaller. (Sᴛᴀᴄᴋ Oᴠᴇʀғʟᴏᴡ)

and `text-transform: uppercase` makes it all CAPS too but but the typeface stays the same size, so `uppercase` typeface will be bigger that `small-caps`

Comment: I think font-variant:small-caps is like a mix of text-transform: capitalize and text-transform: uppercase

Comment: not quite. uppercase makes all letters CAPS. capitalize makes only the first letters of each word CAPS. small-caps makes all CAPS but the height of the CAPS letters will be equal to the height of the non-CAPS letters

Comment: `text-transform` is simply about converting case. `font-variant` ideally is about using a variation of the font specifically designed by font designer which is called [small capitals](http://practicaltypography.com/small-caps.html). In many cases these forms are not present in the font so browsers just do what @pixeltocode has described.

Answer (score 15):

Uppercase is text consisting of normal uppercase characters:

UPPERCASE

Small-caps is like so (taken from [here](http://typophile.com/node/17024)):

[image]

[**Wikipedia article on Small caps**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps)

`text-transform` is buggy in some browsers: See [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-transform).

For example:

> In Internet Explorer for Windows versions up to and including 7, the values lowercase  and uppercase behave like none  if the font-variant property is set to small-caps.

Comment: then what is text-transform:capitalize;

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_text-transform.asp Transforms the first character of each word to uppercase

Comment: i'm also looking at same . see on W3cschools 1. capitalize is   Transforms the first character of each word to uppercase and 2. small-caps is The browser displays a small-caps font . aren't both same thing

Comment: @jitendra no, small-caps is *all* characters uppercase. Capitalize just does this: `Hello World This Is Capitalized Text`

Comment: sorry i was confused in question i wrote uppercase in place of capitalize

Comment: "small-caps is all characters uppercase" but not in ur example image

Comment: @jitendra the characters are all uppercase. Look closely. It's just that the capitals (the uppercase characters) are larger than the normal characters.

Answer (score 7):

In regular Typography there is a huge difference in small-caps and uppercase, as stated by one of the contributors in this forum. Small-caps are capitalised characters with an x-height (almost) equal to lowercase characters.

To mimic this with CSS you can use `font-variant: small-caps;`.

When you use this with a custom font-face (initiated with `@font-face`), it sometimes goes wrong.

Try adding a `text-transform: lowercase;` before you add the `font-variant`:

```
.smallcaps {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

Comment: the text-transform: *lowercase; makes everything lowercase*, and doesn't provide Title Case (which the not-quite-accurately-named *text-transform: capitalize* does).